# Slidify no longer renders accent marks

Tags: r, utf-8, diacritics, r-markdown, slidify

I usually insert accent marks in my slide decks using the utf-8 symbol (i.e. í, é, á, ó, ú, ñ). Today when I used `slidify("index.Rmd")` I received the following warning:

```
Blogification Successful :-)
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
1: In native_encode(text) :
   some characters may not work under the current locale
```

I am not aware of having made any changes other than updating to the newest version of RStudio. Any idea how I can get accent marks back? How can I change the current locale so that it renders utf-8 characters? I don't have this issue when I render a 'normal' .Rmd file (as an html file, for example).

EDIT: Here is some more information about my workflow.

I am using `poirot` and the `blogify(".")` command to render many slide decks at the same time in SublimeText3

Comment: If in English you can use `Sys.setlocale(locale = "en_US.UTF-8")`, let me know if it works.

Comment: I still get the same issue. I have added some more information to the description of the problem.

Comment: At this point is better to see code. Give a reproducible piece of code that reproduce your error and your output without accented letters. Also a provide the output of this function `Sys.getlocale()` maybe it might be helpful to evaluate where the problem is hidden.